# Structure of antiautomorphisms of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Surely, the set of automorphisms of a group $G$ becomes another group $\text{Aut}(G)$. Can I say something about the set of $anti$-automorphisms of a group? It is not a group, but I guess there is a theory on it. At least, can I classify the antiautomorphisms in some nontrivial cases, in any sense?

Comment: By anti-automorphism, I assume you mean $1-1$ and onto $\phi$ such that $\phi(gh)=\phi(h)\phi(g)$

Comment: Yes, exactly. Especially, it can be good if we assume $\phi$ is involutive: $\phi^2=1$, but not necessary.

Comment: You don't get anything new, because if $\phi$ is an anti-automorphism if and only if  the map $x \mapsto \phi(x)^{-1}$ is an automorphism.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every anti-automorphism is just  $\phi(g)=\rho(g^{-1})$ for some automorphism $\rho$. So the set of all automorphisms and anti-automorphisms are a group, and it is isomorphic to either $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ (if $G$ is commutative) or  $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Anti-automorphisms are not a group under composition, but as a coset of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, you could define a group structure on the set which essentially made it isomorphic to $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, and not very interesting.

Involution anti-automorphisms just correspond to involution automorphisms.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, my algebra skill is too poor to see this simple fact before someone tells me :(